# GAE caching objectify queries

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

i have a simple question

in the objectify documentation it says that "Only get(), put(), and delete() interact with the cache. query() is not cached"
http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Global_Cache.

what i'm wondering - if you have one root entity (i did not use @Parent due to all the scalability issues that it seems to have) that all the other entities have a Key to, and you do a query such as

```
ofy.query(ChildEntity.class).filter("rootEntity", rootEntity).list()
```

is this completely bypassing the cache?

If this is the case, is there an efficient caching way to do a query on conditions - or for that matter can you cache a query with a parent where you would have to make an actual ancestor query like the following

```
Key<Parent> rootKey = ObjectifyService.factory().getKey(root)
ofy.query(ChildEntity.class).ancestor(rootKey)
```

Thank you

---

as to one of the comments below i've added an edit

sample dao (ignore the validate method - it just does some null & quantity checks):

this is a sample find all method inside a delegate called from the DAO that the request factory ServiceLocator is using

```
public List<EquipmentCheckin> findAll(Subject subject, Objectify ofy, Event event) {
  final Business business = (Business) subject.getSession().getAttribute(BUSINESS_ATTRIBUTE);
  final List<EquipmentCheckin> checkins = ofy.query(EquipmentCheckin.class).filter(BUSINESS_ATTRIBUTE, business)
    .filter(EVENT_CONDITION, event).list();
  return validate(ofy, checkins);
}
```

now, when this is executed i find that the following method is actually being called in my AbstractDAO.

```
/**
* 
* @param id
* @return
*/
public T find(Long id) {
  System.out.println("finding " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " id = " + id);
  return ObjectifyService.begin().find(clazz, id);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all queries bypass Objectify's integrated memcache and fetch results directly from the datastore.  The datastore provides the (increasingly sophisticated) query engine that understands how to return results; determining cache invalidation for query results is pretty much impossible from the client side.

On the other hand, Objectify4 does offer a hybrid query cache whereby queries are automagically converted to a keys-only query followed by a batch get.  The keys-only query still requires the datastore, but any entity instances are pulled from (and populate on miss) memcache.  It might save you money.

Comment: while debugging i noticed that whenever i do a query - the find method is actually being called - my find method is simply ofy.begin().find(clazz, id) - since this is using get behind the scenes is this pulling a cached entity or still going straight to the datastore since it was called from a query? this was in the docs - "A query() will return cached entity instances, however the (potentially expensive) call to the datastore will still be made." - i guess i'm just wondering what this actually means?  thank you for the help

Comment: Objectify.find() is a get-by-key not a query.  The only difference between find() and get() is that find() returns null vs get() throws an exception when the entity does not exist.

Comment: sorry - i must have worded it wrong - when i actually run my findAll method which is using 'ofy.query(Type.class).filter(Filter.class)' i expect this to bypass the cache - but i find it then goes to my find method (the one in my lcoator - which is simply ofy.find(Type.class, id)) - the doc says that query bypasses the cache, yet the query i call seems to be using my find method - and i think find should technically hit the cache since it's using get() behind the scenes. does this sound correct - i might be way off? i will post the code in an edit real quick - thanks again

Comment: I fear you have lost me entirely.  This might be better done with a separate question tagged with gwt and requestfactory - I am not familiar with how request factory works.  But yes, any Objectify get-by-key will be cache-sensitive (assuming @Cached annotation is on the entity).  Any query will ignore the cache.

Comment: Objectify's way is cost effective: key only queries count as small operations, thefore are free. Gets from Memcache are also free I believe. Anyway, it would be nice to be able to save query results in memcache in order to increase performance for tree like queries. I'm gonna look if it's possible to reuse Vosao's query cache (we talked about it a long time ago) with memcache. The tricky bit is to understand when to invalidate the query https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls